# Calculating travel time along rail network in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, routing, arcgis-10.3

I have a custom railway line network with stations in ArcGIS 10.3. The numbers between each station represent travel time between the two stations.

I would like to be able to select a station and have returned a selection of all stations within a set journey time away.

[image: Rail Network with stations and travel times]

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop and I am very new to Network Analyst.

Comment: Are those travel times encoded into the actual line? Are the stations at nodes (end of lines) or just some point snapped to a line?

Comment: Yeah, I've just added them as labels for clarity. Yes the stations were generated from Calculate Geometry > X/Y Co-ordinate of line start/end point

Comment: I believe what you want to create is what is referred to as [Service areas](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//004700000048000000) in Network Analyst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so you have a field called "tt" which is your travel times, lets assume they represent whole hours. When you are building your network you'll get to the stage of specifying your attributes, default is length. At this point you add a new a attribute, see image below.

[image: Adding an attribute]

Having added it right click on it and select Evaluators and set the type to field and value to your tt field. OK everything and network has your new travel time.

Use the network analyst toolbar to create a service area layer. Then in the properties change impedance to myTravelTime and set default breaks to 5, 10, 15, 20 hours (or what every you desire) as shown below.

[image: Setting properties]

Then add a location and solve and you get what is shown below.

[image: Solved travel time]

Comment: do you how I can generate an output purely based on the network? I am only interested (at this stage) in generating journey times from given stations. At present, I am getting returned polygons similar to yours.

Comment: Very easy. Go to the properties of your service layer. Click on Polygon generation tab and untick the Generate Polygon box. On the Line generation tab tick on Generate lines!